# How to preserve group information while using dplyr do() function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I want to use `dplyr::do` function to run self-defined function over a `data.frame` sub-groups. The problem is that `do()` operation results in a `list` object where **no signature of the group is preserved**.

In particular, my function returns single double value. I wish I have the result as when I use simple `dplyr::summarize` (in the example below, **information about *UniqueCarrier* group is preserved**), e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
data("hflights", package = "hflights")
carriers <- group_by(hflights, UniqueCarrier)

# Information is preserved
carriers.sum.df <- carriers %.% dplyr::summarize(val = min(ArrDelay, na.rm=T))
head(carriers.sum.df, 3)

## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## 
##   UniqueCarrier val
## 1            AA -39
## 2            AS -43
## 3            B6 -44
```

Instead of receiving a list of single values (in the example below, **information about *UniqueCarrier* group is NOT preserved**), e.g.:

```
# Information is lost 
carriers.sum.list <- do(carriers, .f = function(df) min(df$ArrDelay, na.rm=T))
head(carriers.sum.list, 3)

## [[1]]
## [1] -39
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] -43
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] -44
```

Comment: I have just tried it out - this new solution totaly ROCKS! = D Thank you, Mr Hadley!